# C++; How to write to an Vect3b pointer of opencv in a function

Tags: c++, function, opencv, pointers, vector

I have a small problem. I am having a function using a function with 2 Mat pointer objects given, but im having trouble writing to outImg channels to update the img.

```
void convolve5(Mat *inputImg, Mat *outImg, int *kernel5) {
     int channelvaluepixel = inputImg->at<Vect3b>(x,y)[channel];
     // loads of changes happening here
     outImg->at<Vect3b>(x,y)[0] = channelvaluepixel;
}
```

Since outImg is a pointer i cannot point to its adress to change it, so i tried this to change the value within the pointer:

```
*outImg->at<Vect3b>(x,y)[0] = channelvaluepixel;
```

But this would not work either since the compiler gives me an:

```
Error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'unsigned char')
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: You are dereferencing whole expression `outImg->at<Vect3b>(x,y)[0]` instead of just `(*outImg).at<Vect3b>(x,y)[0] = channelvaluepixel;`

Comment: Can't reproduce; original code, i.e. `outImg->at<Vec3b>(x,y)[0]`, works for me (Windows 10, Visual Studio Prof. 2017, OpenCV 4.0.0).

Comment: > _Since outImg is a pointer i cannot point to its adress to change it_  


I think you might have some misconceptions about the member access operator (`->`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dereferencing whole expression `outImg->at<Vect3b>(x,y)[0]` instead of just `(*outImg).at<Vect3b>(x,y)[0] = channelvaluepixel;`